# Get the input value of a directive inside the typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, ionic2

The input that I pass to a directive is correctly shown inside the html file, but I don't get its value inside the typescript file. How can I access it inside the typescript file?

Here is an example:

I have a directive, which is defined in `test-info.ts` as follows:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'test-info',
 templateUrl: 'test-info.html'
})
export class TestInfo {
  @Input('location') location;
  constructor(...) {
     console.log('this.location: ' + this.location ); //------> Prints null
  }
```

inside `test-info.html` I have:

```
{{location}}
```

I use this directive inside another html `user.html` file:

```
<test-info [location]='location'> </test-info>
```

The location is shown correctly in the `user.html`, but the console.log command in the .ts file prints null.

**Edit:**
In `user.ts`, location is assigned to in an Ajax call. Most probably this is why the constructor or ngOnInit() misses this value. But how can I get it when it is updated?

Comment: It's because, you couldn't use inputs in constructor. You could get access to these inputs in `ngOnInit()`. It's called right after the directive's data-bound properties have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

Comment: I get the same result with `ngOnInit()` and `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ngOnChanges` hook. If you really change the right value then you should get it in that hook.

```
ngOnChanges() {
   console.log('this.location: ' + this.location );
}
```

Another way is wrapping component in `*ngIf`:

```
<test-info *ngIf="location" [location]='location'> </test-info>
```

Comment: This did not quiet work for me as I had multiple async values. I ended up moving the async calls to test-info file.